# IIS 10 on Windows Server 2016 + ASP.NET Core 6 = CORS issues

Tags: asp.net-core, iis

My question is **how do I configure IIS website hosting ASP.NET app to allow any cross origin requests**? Now the details:

I have an ASP.NET Core app (JSON service really) that gets called by other web apps with different origin.
This of course triggers CORS errors.
I was able to solve CORS errors while it was running in Kestrel.
I have at least 2 ways that are working - one looks like this:

```
    builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddDefaultPolicy(
                          policy =>
                          {
                              policy
                                .AllowAnyOrigin()
                                .AllowAnyMethod()
                                .AllowAnyHeader();
                          });
    });
    ...
    app.UseCors();
```

The other looks like this:

```
    app.Use((context, next) =>
    {
        context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "*" });
        context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", new[] { "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept" });
        context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", new[] { "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" });
        context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", new[] { "true" });
        if (context.Request.Method == "OPTIONS")
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = 200;
            return context.Response.WriteAsync("OK");
        }
        // Call the next delegate/middleware in the pipeline.
        return next(context);
    });
```

Both work, but now I need to host that same app under IIS. So I loaded the "hosting bundle" created a web site, pointed it to the published app as per docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-7.0)
It works on its own, but when called from another origin I get CORS error.
Out of the box the error is about Access-Control-Allow-Origin header missing (even though ASP.NET app adds it).

So I add custom headers on IIS like so

```
   <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Api-Key, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization" />
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
        </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
```

Now instead of the error about Access-Control-Allow-Origin missing I get one that says there are 2 values for it.
So then I remove the code in the ASP.NET app that adds those headers, but leave the xml to add them in IIS.
Now I get a CORS error about preflight request not getting status 200 on it. From what I read, preflight request sends OPTION and as long as it gets 200 back (like I do in C#) it's fine. It just needs to be on IIS as it's not getting into ASP.NET app at that point.
Looking at similar questions I tried a bunch of things - various xml in web.config and at one point a redirect for OPTION, but nothing worked so far

Something that seems relevant is
[image]

I did try removing it with

```
  <handlers>
    <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
```

That did not help either.
Bottom line is

- **when IIS has no Access-Control-Allow-Origin header, regardless of
  what ASP.NET app has, I get "missing Access-Control-Allow-Origin
  header"**.
- **when IIS has Access-Control-Allow-Origin header and ASP.NET does too,
  I get an error that there are 2 and only one is allowed**.
- **when IIS has Access-Control-Allow-Origin header and ASP.NET does not,
  I get an error that preflight request did not get 200 status**.

Latest thing I tried was installing and configuring CORS module on IIS
That did not work either. See comments

Comment: Have you installed [CORS Module](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/iis-cors-module) in iis? If not, please install it in iis, and if cors has been configured in your project, then you don’t need to set it in iis.

Comment: Just installed it in IIS per your instruction, restored IIS website to no custom headers nothing special except aspNet handler, same result as before "..blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

Comment: Getting started with CORS module is not just installing it, https://blogs.iis.net/iisteam/getting-started-with-the-iis-cors-module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After running into the 404 issue with IIS CORS module (see my other answer) and looking a little harder at what preflight request looks like I found that I was able to overcome it in ASP.NET code like so :

```
app.Use((context, next) =>
{
    context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "*" });
    context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", new[] { "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, additional-header" });
    context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", new[] { "HEAD, GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" });
    context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", new[] { "true" });
    if (context.Request.Method == "OPTIONS")
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = 200;
        return context.Response.WriteAsync("OK");
    }
    // Call the next delegate/middleware in the pipeline.
    return next(context);
});
```

The important change compared to what I posted in the question is

```
context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers"
```

now contains

```
additional-header
```

in the list

If you looks at the description in that configure IIS CORS module link: https://blogs.iis.net/iisteam/getting-started-with-the-iis-cors-module

You will see that preflight request is a request with method OPTION that sends this header ("additional-header") and so by adding it in the allowed headers I was able to send the answer to it.
The link tells you that the correct answer is status 204 which is wrong. When I tried that the browser  complained that it did not get 200, so I switched it back to 200 and then it worked.

I did not remove IIS CORS module installation from the machine but I did remove the configuration in web.config for it.

I am not sure if having it installed is part of the solution or not (it could be).

Answer (score 2):

Based on the comments I was able to get past CORS. Thank you samwu and Lex Li. 
Had to install CORS module on IIS and add this in the **web.config** of the website in question inside of **<system.webServer>** tag:

```
  <cors enabled="true">
    <add origin="*">
        <allowHeaders allowAllRequestedHeaders="true" />
        <allowMethods>
            <add method="GET" />
            <add method="HEAD" />
            <add method="POST" />
            <add method="PUT" /> 
            <add method="DELETE" />
            <add method="OPTION" />             
        </allowMethods>
    </add>      
  </cors>
```

Helpful links both from the comments by those 2 awesome people:
**Install**: https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/iis-cors-module 
**Configure**: https://blogs.iis.net/iisteam/getting-started-with-the-iis-cors-module

**HOWEVER**: **I then ran into a very strange glitch where I was getting 404 on a url that had been constructed incorrectly by concatinating the origin and target urls together. It only happened when the app was under IIS with this config and not when it was under Kestrel so I still blame IIS and was not able to resolve that issue**.

Comment: It's great that you provided an answer, but the However-part should be posted as a new, separate question.

Comment: I would otherwise agree with you Peter, but because I was able to find a different actually working answer I decided to leave the other answer here with the "however" to provide a more detailed picture of the situation. Since I do not intend at this point  to solve the however part I will not be posting another question